# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

i have started working on laravel 5.3 . Building a basic login page .

**This is my homeController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

**my User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

earlier there was a single route.php but now in Laravel 5.3 there are api.php,console and web.php in route directory ,hence i am not getting any resource to find where to add route commands .

**my api.php in routes folder**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

**my web.php in routes folder**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

**my console.php in route folder**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Console Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of your Closure based console
| commands. Each Closure is bound to a command instance allowing a
| simple approach to interacting with each command's IO methods.
|
*/

Artisan::command('inspire', function () {
    $this->comment(Inspiring::quote());
})->describe('Display an inspiring quote');
```

**Route :: get('/', function () { return view('welcome');} );**

this is working fine since i am able to see homepage but other  routes are not working .when i click on login or register this exception arrise

Answer (score 0):

For more regarding 5.3 routing, follow this document posted by @matt..

https://mattstauffer.co/blog/routing-changes-in-laravel-5-3

also read the document in details of laravel 5.3 routing [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing).

You should not use api.php unless untill your are customizing laravel's out of the box route qualified links, to customize your routing use web.php instead.